# vector insert() warning message

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm a c++ beginner. I get this warning message in my code:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xmemory(208): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xmemory(280) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct<double&>(int *,_Other)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int,
1>              _Other=double &
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\vector(668) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Cons_val<std::allocator<_Ty>,int,double&>(_Alloc &,_Ty1 *,_Ty2)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<int>,
1>              _Ty1=int,
1>              _Ty2=double &
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\vector(688) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<_Ty>::emplace_back<double&>(_Valty)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int,
1>              _Valty=double &
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\vector(675) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec> std::vector<_Ty>::emplace<double&>(std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>,_Valty)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<int,std::allocator<int>>,
1>              _Ty=int,
1>              _Valty=double &
1>          ]
1>          preprocessDoc.cpp(14054) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec> std::vector<_Ty>::insert<double&>(std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>,_Valty)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<int,std::allocator<int>>,
1>              _Ty=int,
1>              _Valty=double &
1>          ]
```

The code compiles without any error however I want to get rid of this warning. The line where I am getting the warning is:

```
void PreprocessDoc::AddDisplay(double d_display, int pattern)
{
    if(pattern==1)
    {
        d_displayYT.insert(d_displayYT.end(), d_display);  //this line
        YTtoYrn();
    }
}
```

Any help would be good

Comment: That warning is pretty clear IMO. Converting a `double` to an `int` looses the numbers beyond the decimal point. Make it clear that you ***really want that*** using a `static_cast<int>(d_display)`.

Comment: Not the answer, but something to consider.  Look into the vector::push_back() method to simplify this code..

Answer (score 2):

```
_Myvec=std::_Vector_val<int,std::allocator<int>>,
```

The compiler is telling you that you're converting a double to int.  If the double is say `42.666` what is stored is just `42`.  It's warning you in case this was not intended.

If that's really what you want then do as [David suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41110065/1294207).  If it's not then you need to change the type the vector holds.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
    d_displayYT.insert(d_displayYT.end(), d_display);  //this line
```

to:

```
    d_displayYT.insert(d_displayYT.end(), static_cast<int>(d_display));
```

Comment: Should we be so hasty? What is `d_displayYT` and why does it need a double? This is the answer to the question, but might not be sound advice ...

Comment: Thanks David! Ben, `d_displayYT` is of type `int`